# Using tesseract-ocr-3.02.equ.tar for Tesseract in an iOS Application

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, ocr, tesseract

I have recently downloaded "tesseract-ocr-3.02.equ.tar", which when opened contains a .traineddata file to work with Tesseract OCR Engine.  I was wondering how I would use this file for use in an iOS Application (i.e. - in xCode) - similar to example projects such as "PocketOCR" which has multiple files stored in a "tessdata" folder.

Any Help would be greatly appreciated?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Place `equ.traineddata` in `tessdata` folder and call Tesseract with language parameter set to "equ".

Comment: I keep getting an error once I do that: "Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=2,address=0x8)" How would I go about solving this?